# Creating kube-dns ConfigMap in kube-system namespace on new Kubernetes 1.6 cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns

I am trying to follow the example in [this blog post](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/04/configuring-private-dns-zones-upstream-nameservers-kubernetes.html) to supply my pods with upstream DNS servers.

I created a new GKE cluster in us-east1-d (where 1.6.0 is available according to the April 4 entry [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes)).

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:36:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:24:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I Then defined a ConfigMap in the following YAML file, kube-dns-cm.yml:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: ConfigMap
 metadata:
   name: kube-dns
   namespace: kube-system
 data:
   upstreamNameservers: |
     ["1.2.3.4"]
```

When I try to create the ConfigMap, I am told it already exists:

```
$ kubectl create -f kube-dns-cm.yml
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "kube-dns-cm.yml": configmaps "kube-dns" already exists
```

I tried deleting the existing ConfigMap and replacing it with my own, but when I subsequently create pods, they do not seem to have taken effect (names are not resolved as I hoped). Is there more to the story than is explained in the blog post (e.g., restarting the kube-dns service, or the pods)? Thanks!

EDIT: Deleting and recreating the ConfigMap actually *does* work, but not entirely the way I was hoping. My docker registry is on a private (corporate) network, and resolving the name of the registry requires the upstream nameservers. So I *cannot* use the DNS name of the registry on my pod yaml file, but the pods created from that yaml file will have the desired DNS resolution (after the ConfigMap is replaced)

Answer (score 1):

It has been my experience with `ConfigMap` that when I update it, the changes don't seem to reflect in the running pod that is using the `ConfigMap`.

So when I delete the pod and when pod comes up again it shows the latest `ConfigMap`.

Hence I suggest try restarting the `kube-dns` pod, which seems to use this `ConfigMap` you created.

Answer (score 1):

`kube-dns` pod applied with recent configMap changes after it is restarted. But, still got the similar issue.

Check logs using `kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c dnsmasq`

`kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kubedns`

Tried changing `--cluster-dns` value to hosts server "nameserver" ip which is already connecting for me both internal and external network. Restarted kubelet service for changes to take effect.

`Environment="KUBELET_DNS_ARGS=**--cluster-dns=<<your-nameserver-resolver>>** --cluster-domain=cluster.local"` in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`

That works !!! Now containers able to connect external network.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `ConfigMap` config is correct, while you **do need** restart `kube-dns`.

Because `ConfigMap` is injected into pod by either `env` pairs or volumes(`kube-dns` use volume), you need to restart the target pod(here I mean **all the** `kube-dns` pod) to make it take effect.

Another suggestion is that, from you description, you only want this upstream dns help you access your docker registry which is in private network, then I suggest you may want to try `stubDomains` in that [post you referred](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/04/configuring-private-dns-zones-upstream-nameservers-kubernetes.html).

And **most important**, you need to check you `dnsPolicy` is set to `ClusterFirst`, although from your description, I guess it is.

Hope this will help you out.